# Large files with msdeploy

Tags: msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

We are trying to use Web Deploy to improve our deployment.

Everything works internally but once we try to deploy to our online environment than msdeploy hangs on files lager than 1 MB.

If we remove those files, the sync works with msdeploy.

The client tries a few times to upload the file and then gives the following error:
Warning: Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object MSDeploy.contentPath (sourcePath).
Attempt 4 of 25.
Info: Using ID '789c2466-2bae-4b56-b67d-1a1743cdb0f6' for connections to the remote server.

On the server we see the following error:
Content-Type: application/msdeploy
Version: 8.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 7.1.1070.1
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: 789c2466-2bae-4b56-b67d-1a1743cdb0f6
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"objectName="filePath",absolutePath=".*web.config$"objectName="filePath"
Provider: contentPath, Path: demo.com
Tracing deployment agent exception. Request ID '789c2466-2bae-4b56-b67d-1a1743cdb0f6'.
 Request Timestamp: '5/07/2011 11:29:56'. Error Details:
System.Net.HttpListenerException: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Close()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventSerializer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
Anyone any suggestions to fix the problem?

Comment: any luck with this? I know this was posted last year but I have a dev experiencing the exact same error when doing a MSDeploy and files larger than 1 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had this issue so cannot give you a specific fix but the microsoft documentation says

[Why does remote deployment fail for large files, although local deployment succeeds?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx)

Typically when you deploy to production servers you are deploying across a firewall. 
If you get end-of-stream errors on large files, check the settings on the firewall.

Unfortuately it doesnt give specifics regarding the firewall setting to check

Comment: I confirm that in my case this was the problem. Small file went trough but 4MB+ files (DLLS) failed.